# Copying Contents of One ViewGroup to Another

Tags: android, viewgroup

Hi I need to get a duplicate of a ViewGroup but not with the exact same location by sort of copying and pasting a ViewGroup. So I tried to do this and this is the result:

```
public void ViewGroupCopy(ViewGroup source,int sourceOffset,ViewGroup destination,int destinationOffset){
    for(int i=sourceOffset;i<source.getChildCount();i++){
        View view = source.getChildAt(i);
        source.removeView(view);
        destination.addView(view, destinationOffset+i, view.getLayoutParams());
    }
```

I used the method in this block of code:

```
            Activity host = (Activity) this.getContext();
            View contentView = host.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    ViewGroup children = (ViewGroup) contentView;
    ViewGroup oldChildren = (ViewGroup) contentView;
    children.removeAllViews();
    children.addView(new Preview(context));
    ViewGroupCopy(oldChildren,0,children,1);
```

For your additional info, this class extends a view.

Well I am getting this in my LogCat when I try to use this.

09-08 16:34:30.212: E/AndroidRuntime(10992): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to           start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.worknwalk/com.example.worknwalk.Text}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 count=0

Could somebody please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using same index for getting a view from source group. Every time you remove a view from source you will get a new view at that index. Also there was a possible bug for destinationOffset+i when sourceOffset > 0. There may be no bug here but I am not entirely sure about the behavior when you for example add an item with index 10 to a list with 6 items. It may or may not crash. Anyway, try this:

```
public void ViewGroupCopy(ViewGroup source, int sourceOffset,
        ViewGroup destination, int destinationOffset) {

    int limit = source.getChildCount() - sourceOffset;

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        View view = source.getChildAt(sourceOffset);
        source.removeView(view);
        destination.addView(view, destinationOffset + i,
                view.getLayoutParams());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that and I got this error:


09-08 18:02:04.189: E/AndroidRuntime(702): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.worknwalk/com.example.worknwalk.Text}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Then I suggest something like view.setParent(null) or use iterator instead of for-loop

Comment: I get your idea but I don't see any such method because I think the ViewGroup (LinearLayout) is the parent.

Comment: I did a small update on the method of yours. Try it now and see if it works. It should work this time ;)

Comment: Hmm... I'm working on it too. I tried using your method and I got another IndexOutOfBoundException at the same place. But this time index=2, count=1. I have to get rid of the parent somehow....